# Mainpulating a QObject created from a button press

Tags: c++, string, qt, qobject

I am making an application, and at some point, the user will be creating some sort of from/survey. When creating, the user selects the various question types etc. by pressing a button and a new object will be created.

To create a new section, for example:

```
void CreateSurvey::question_section()
{
 QLabel *sectionTitle = new QLabel();
 sectionTitle->setText("New Section");
 layout->addWidget(sectionTitle);

 QLabel *titleLabel = new QLabel("Title");
 QLineEdit *titleEdit = new QLineEdit("New Section");

 QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
 hLayout->addWidget(titleLabel);
 hLayout->addWidget(titleEdit);

 layout->addLayout(hLayout);

 sectionCount++;
 qDebug() << "sections: " << sectionCount;
}
```

When the application is running, the text 'TitleEdit' will be edited by the user for the title of the section. 
Say this has been called 3 times, so there are 3 sections. How do I get the strings entered for the title for each section?, or how do i get the string entered for a particular section?

Thanks

Comment: You need to store objects you are interested in. Otherwise you won't (simply) access them.

Comment: How do I do that? In an array?

Comment: The layout holds all the objects you're adding. You can cycle around and extract the data you need.

Comment: @Phauk: any container you want. There are plenty of them in Qt library and in std.

Comment: @bibi, How do you mean 'cycle around and extract the data you need'? I can't work out how to do this

Comment: I tried to setup an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a container like `QVector` to store your `QLineEdit` objects. Use this container to access the text of each `QLineEdit` object.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class Survey : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Survey(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        resize(600, 400);
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        layout()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Add line edit");
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Survey::addLineEdit);
        layout()->addWidget(button);    
        QPushButton *print_button = new QPushButton("Print all text");    
        connect(print_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < line_edit_vector.size(); i++)
                qDebug() << getText(i);
        });    
        layout()->addWidget(print_button);
    }

    QString getText(int index) const
    {
        if(line_edit_vector.size() > index)
            return line_edit_vector[index]->text();
        return QString();
    }

private slots:
    void addLineEdit()
    {
        QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit("Line edit");
        layout()->addWidget(edit);
        line_edit_vector.append(edit);
    }

private:
    QVector<QLineEdit*> line_edit_vector;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Survey survey;
    survey.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a go at that.  
The next step would be to store it as JSON, so then the same survey could be created again. Is that possible?

Comment: @Phauk Sure. See [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html).

Comment: This has been really helpful. I am intending to store QLayouts in my vector.
I am running a quick example to try store some QLayouts,  and then print them out again.
     ` question_vector.append(dLayout);
     question_vector.append(sLayout);
     question_vector.append(eLayout);

     connect(ui->submitButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]
            {   
                    surveyLayout->addItem(question_vector.at(0));
     });`

However when I press submitButton, a blank space is added, not the layout (and widgets) i'm trying add.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Cant work out how to format the comment for the code :(

Comment: @Phauk I don't know the design of your application, but something you should consider: instead of adding a layout when you click a button, why don't you just show a widget that is hidden? Set this layout on that widget.

Comment: I have an undefined number of widgets, so they are created and stored (hopefully) within the QVector. I'll then save this QVector in JSON,  and then can use that to recreate the same widgets.

Comment: I understand what is going wrong now - Sorry I havnt been particularly clear, I was becoming overwhelmed.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

in your `CreateSurvey` header add a

```
public slot:
    void title_changed();
```

in your `question_section` method, add a connection:

```
connect(titleEdit,SIGNAL(editingFinished()),this,SLOT(title_changed()));
```

and add the `title_changed` slot:

```
void CreateSurvey::title_changed()
{
    QLineEdit *titleEdit=qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(sender());
    if (titleEdit) {
      qDebug() << titleEdit->text();
    }
}
```

In this way every time the line gets edited the slot `title_changed` will be triggered.

if you want to know all the titles once just **one** has been edited, use this slot:

```
void CreateSurvey::title_changed()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < layout->count(); ++i) {
         QLineEdit *titleEdit=qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(layout->itemAt(i));
         if (titleEdit) {
             qDebug() << titleEdit->text();
         }
     }
}
```