# Accessing aspects of QObject stored in QVector

Tags: qt, qobject, qvector

I have a QVector of QObjects `QVector<QWidget*> question_vector;`. These widgets are questions. (My application is like a questionnaire thing).

When creating a questionnaire, question types are chosen from the selection on a comboBox, and within Questions class, the question is created,  and stored in the QVector.

```
void CreateSurvey::comboBox_selection(const QString &arg1)
{
    if(arg1 == "Single Line Text")
    {
    Question *singleLineText = new Question("Single Line Text");
    surveyLayout->addWidget(singleLineText);
    question_vector.append(singleLineText);
    qDebug() << "Number of items: "<< question_vector.size();

    } ...
}

void Question::create_singleLineEdit()
{
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLabel *titleLabel = new QLabel("Title");
    vLayout->addWidget(titleLabel);
    QLineEdit *inputText = new QLineEdit;
    vLayout->addWidget(inputText);
    QLabel *commentsLabel = new QLabel("Comments");
    vLayout->addWidget(commentsLabel);
    QLineEdit *commentsText = new QLineEdit;
    vLayout->addWidget(commentsText);

    ui->frame->setLayout(vLayout);
}
```

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF2D3.png)

The SingleLineEdit is the widget, the title, titleEdit, comments, commentsEdit.
How do I access, for example the text from an individual component of the widget, the commentsText QLineEdit?

Comment: you have already asked similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098139/mainpulating-a-qobject-created-from-a-button-press and got answer. What is exacly your problem?

Comment: Yeah that one has line_edit_vector[index]->text();  getting the text of QVector<QLineEdit*> line_edit_vector;      so now im moving on and having  QVector<QWidget>question_vector;  as different types of widget are getting added rather than just lineedits,   so if i have a lineedit within the object at  question_vector[3],  how do i get the information from that?  question_vector[3]->commentsText->text(); doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've managed to solve what I was trying to do (at least partly)

So I had here

```
void Question::create_singleLineEdit()
{
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLabel *titleLabel = new QLabel("Title");
    vLayout->addWidget(titleLabel);
    QLineEdit *inputText = new QLineEdit;
    vLayout->addWidget(inputText);
    QLabel *commentsLabel = new QLabel("Comments");
    vLayout->addWidget(commentsLabel);
    QLineEdit *commentsText = new QLineEdit;
    vLayout->addWidget(commentsText);
    ui->frame->setLayout(vLayout);
}
```

What I did was changed stuff like `QLineEdit *commentsText = new QLineEdit;` to
`section_commentsText = newLineEdit;` - Having `QTextEdit *section_commentsText` in my question.h.

I was then able to do

```
Question *object = question_vector[0];
QString text = object->section_commentsText->text();
qDebug() << text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the element to the a QLineEdit:

```
QLineEdit *line_edit = dynamic_cast <QLineEdit *> (question_vector[3]);

if (line_edit)
{
   QString text = line_edit->text();
}
```

This is a basic aspect of C++ programming; you probably should do some reading on C++ classes, how to derive them, how to use base class pointers and derived class pointers, and so on.

Comment: You'll need to extend your Question class to provide access to the content contained in the QLineEdit. The casting I proposed is incorrect; I misunderstand what your Question class was. Since Question encapsulates a bunch of widgets, you'll need to add methods to Question so that external callers can get the text: